# Mock Testing with Named Credentials

Tags: unit-test, httpcalloutmock, namedcredentials

I've successfully implemented [Named Credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000206761&language=en_US) for a Basic Auth integration callout.

However, when I went to write my test method, I noticed one minor annoyance.

When I try to create a `HttpCalloutMock` class with the Named Credentials syntax,

```
req.setEndpoint('callout:My_Named_Credential/' + uri;);
```

I get an exception:

> System.StringException: unknown protocol: callout

Also, as far as I can tell (based on the current documentation), there doesn't seem to be any way to programmatically access the properties of the Named Credential.

So, in order to set my `HttpCalloutMock`endpoint, I now need to hardcode the URL I entered (or put it in a custom label).

Obviously, this added dependency is not idea for maintenance.

### Update

Even more frustrating... it turns out the exception is still thrown even after hardcoding the endpoint in the `HttpCalloutMock`.

Comment: also would have made a lot more sense if they did this as an actual protocol, i.e. "callout://My_Named_Credentials/some_path", if it's a valid url that seems like it would play nicer with other methods, as opposed to "callout:My_Named_Credentials/some_path", which is only a valid URI which doesn't make sense for a callout

Comment: @RalphCallaway Or allowed you to actually pass the NCred object into a specific method on the request, or better, just access the data programmatically.  I don't foresee this feature being useful for anyone who has strayed away from the basic auth (for example HMAC signatures)

Comment: it just means it would be more likely that other internal things don't misbehave, i.e. "Not a valid protocol", since there isn't a protocol in "callout:My_named_credential". Underneath the covers there a ton of java code intended to work with URLs so if the named credential was actually a URL I suspect there would be less annoying gotchas like you've encountered

Comment: and yeah, seems like it would have made more sense to have the named credential not be endpoint specific, but instead have you set the endpoint and then .setCredential() on the request

Comment: @RalphCallaway Making it endpoint specific does increase the security.  It can only be sent to the endpoint it specified for.  If SF is comprised, then they could post the username and password to their own system

Comment: salesforce really should have created an new Interface that is could be passed into the HTTPRequest object (something like setupNamedCredAuth()).  It would have a single method signature that would look something like this void setupAuth(HttpRequest request, Sting Username, String Password);.  The request would pass itself and the username and pass into this method before http.send(). This would allow you to determine exactly how the authentication is created (basic, hmac sig, etc) but still not give you direct access to the username and password.

Comment: It is endpoint specific because one of the main use cases that it is intended to handle is where code is deployed to staged environments; with a named credential, the code can stay the same and reference the same named credential ("callout:whatevs") but each org would define that named credential such that in one org it points to a staging endpoint and another might point to a production endpoint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ahh, new Salesforce features.

That said, if you're mocking, you're not really testing any of that functionality, just how the response is handled. You're also not calling a real server, so the endpoint doesn't really matter. I'm never a fan of having to do hoops around limited Test functionality, but seems like we can make do in the interim.

So for the callout class, just change the endpoint to use or not use the named credential if you're running a test. If the replacement URL is deterministic, you can still create mock classes that work on multiple endpoints. And no hardcoding required ...

```
String namedCredential = 'My_Named_Credential';
String path = '/some/path';
String uri;
if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
  // would probably want to put a method for this in a TestUtil so you could get
  // to and from a mock path deterministically from a namedCredential/path combo
  uri = 'http://callout.' + namedCredential + '.com' + path; 
} else {
  uri = 'callout:' + namedCredential + path;
}
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(uri);
```

Comment: Side Note:  Use a Ternary operator instead of an `if/else`.  You'll get 100% Code Coverage.  `String uri = Test.isRunningTest() ? 'http://callout.' + namedCredential + '.com' + path : 'callout:' + namedCredential + path;`

Comment: Also, if you use the MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock version, it does seem to let you set an endpoint like multimock.setStaticResource('callout:Google_Analytics...')

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer to the original question, but an alternative solution I use for testing external integrations is setting up a single MockHttpGenerator as follows...

This enables me to use a mix of named credentials and regular URLs as needed; just need to make sure your named credential's name also exist in URL. i.e. `callout:TaxJar_API` vs `api.taxjar.com`

```
@isTest
public class MyMockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();

        /**
         * Support Various APIs
         */

        // TaxJar API
        if (req.getEndpoint().toLowerCase().contains('taxjar')) {

            // All responses are in JSON format
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            // Assume requests are successful, unless changed below
            res.setStatusCode(200);
            
            // Categories
            if (req.getEndpoint().contains('/categories')) {
                
                // Mock response from /categories endpoint
                res.setBody('{"categories": [' +
                    '{' +
                        '"name": "Installation Services", ' +
                        '"product_tax_code": "19000", ' +
                        '"description": "Installation services separately stated ' +
                                        'from sales of tangible personal property."' +
                    '}' +
                ']}');
            }
        }

        // Return generic response
        else {
            res.setBody('{"foo": "bar"}');
        }

        // Return mock response
        return res;
    }
}
```