# Using Named Credential URL in Apex Class returning null static resource in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest-api

I am implementing Named Credentials to replace how we do callout for a certain endpoint.

One of my current test methods looks something like this:

```
@isTest
private static void test_method1() {
    MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock multimock = new MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock();
    multimock.setStaticResource('https://api.fakeapi.com/users?login=nomnomnom&api_version=1.1.1.1', 'StaticResourceName');
    multimock.setStaticResource('https://api.fakeapi.com/bakedgoods?api_version=1.1.1.1', 'AnotherStaticResourceName'');
    multimock.setStatusCode(200);
    multimock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, multimock);
    Test.startTest();

    APIClient client = new APIClient();
    APIClient.APIMethod method1 = client.getSomeInfo('');


    APIClient.APIMethod method2 = client.getSomeOtherInfo('nomnomnom');

    Test.stopTest();

}
```

Now if I use the old way of populating a URL in my request header like so:

```
req.setEndpoint('https://api.fakeapi.com/bakedgoods' + bakedgoodId);
```

Everything works smoothly. As soon as I update the request endpoint in the Client apex class to take a named credential URL like so:

```
req.setEndpoint('callout:NamedCredentialURL/' + bakedgoodId);
```

The test class throws a "Static Resource not found: " error.

I have tried many things with fruitless results, I have attempted using the named credential URL in the MultiMock assignment in the test class itself. I have scoured the documentation and nothing has come up to solve this(both from Salesforce and from SE). I would like to avoid using !isRunningTest notation in my client as that seems to be more of duct tape than an actual solution.

I have trimmed the code to have the relevant parts, so something might seem amiss, but I'm open to ideas!

Comment: Seems like [this has been an issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75490/mock-testing-with-named-credentials) for a while.

Comment: Instead of directly using `req.setEndpoint('callout:Named..')`, can you try as `String endpoint = 'callout:Named..'; req.setEndpoint(endpoint)` and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifying a named credential in `req.setEndpoint()`, then you need to specify exactly the same string when setting up the mocks with `MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock`.

In other words:

`mock.setStaticResource('callout:NamedCredentialName/urlpath?id=11111', 'StaticResourceName');`